# How do determine why Gatekeeper is rejecting a signed executable?

Tags: macos, code-signing, macos-catalina, osx-gatekeeper

We have a multi-platform suite of command-line executables and libraries that we ported to Mac. The file layout was

- /Applications/

  - (company folder)/

    - (our UI).app
    - (product name)/

      - bin/

        - ...executalbes...
      - lib/

        - ...dylibs...
      - (other stuff)/...

This was shipped in a DMG that was codesigned, as was the app. This worked OK until Catalina.

Now on Catalina, we have codesigned all the executables, dylibs, apps (including ones nested in the top-level app's framework), frameworks, and the DM itself. When we notarize it the resulting JSON log lists no issues. However, when I run any of our executables **that depends on one of our dylibs** I get a pop-up telling me the "developer cannot be identified". Even though it has been signed and notarized OK. Running codesign with -dvvv option includes the following:

- SHA-256 hash choice
- list of Authority entries terminating in Apple Root CA
- TeamIdentifier entry
- Timestamp
- Runtime: 10.13.0

**Question** How can I fix this, or at least get Gatekeeper to tell me *why* it's not accepting this file? Maybe a log, or an equivalent of spctl --assess for files rather than apps?

Observations

- This only happens when

  - the OS is Catalina
  - it's under the /Applications folder
  - outside of /Applications (e.g. in a folder on desktop) it only happens sometimes (and sometimes it claims a  dylib can't be loaded on first attempt, then succeeds if tried a moment later)
  - the executable depends on one or more of our dylibs (standalone ones run OK)
  - the executable has the com.apple.quarantine xattr set

    - I've tried to mix'n'match between clean and downloaded (i.e. quarantine-xattr'd files) and the problem only arises if the executable is quarantined; it doesn't care if a non-quarantined executable loads a quaratined dylib
- The signing operation was done via codesign with args "--deep --strict --timestamp --options runtime", and then verified

  - EDIT: I've since updated this to include some the Hardened Runtime entitlements to fix another build issue, but it hasn't helped with this one
- The executables depend on the dylibs via @rpath (as reported by otool -L)

  - EDIT: I'ver tried replacing the @rpath with @executable_path/../lib in each case, and that hasn't helped

Comment: Are the dylibs signed with the same identity as your main app?

Comment: Yes, they are all signed with the same identity

Comment: There may be something informative written to the console log when the load fails.

Comment: Does the notarization log show all of the files you expect? I think it's under "ticketContents".

Answer (score 0):

One more tidbit that Apple haven't added to their documentation; if you are distributing a dylib rather than a full app bundle, you can't staple the notarisation results to it. So far, so [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow), and Catalina should verify the notarisation online when the software is installed.

However, **the notarised dylib will be rejected on the build machine** unless you add it to a container (i.e. zip/dmg), remove the original copy, then extract it from the zip again after the notarisation has been fully accepted (i.e. you have received the success email). It appears that the notarisation is only checked when the file is created.

You can always run it from within XCode, but not on it's own, without removing and replacing the binary.